# Reopen Diana Allers romance question

Tags: discussion, reopen

> **Subject Question:  [When is the "lock-in" point for the Diana Allers romance?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/101802/6274)**

The above question was closed as duplicate of this one:

> [Can you romance multiple people?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54915/can-you-romance-multiple-people)

My question is *very specific*, and even calls out the fact that *generally* the answer in the proposed duplicate *is* applicable.  However, there is documentation that the *specific* case I'm referring to is unique in some ways - ways which may make the general answer not applicable.

So, could we re-open the subject question?  Or will I need to post a bounty on the duplicate if I want anyone to be motivated towards specifically addressing this particular case?

If it will help, consider that the question *could* be effectively re-worded to be "Is there a 'lock-in' point for the Diana Allers romance?" or "When is the 'lock-in' point for the Diana Allers romance?" - something which is *not* well addressed (if at all) by the proposed duplicate - and achieve the same end.

**EDIT**

To clarify my last point:

The proposed duplicate "Can you romance multiple people?" is exactly as its title says.  That question can be simply answered with a "Yes/No" and needs little to no further elaboration.

My question is a little more than its title belies.  (And perhaps I should edit the title a bit to better reflect this - that seems to happen a lot with my questions.)  If one were to read the question instead of just the title it would be apparent, that I not only need to know *whether* I can romance multiple people when one of those is Diana Allers but also, I need to know *when* that relationship gets locked in.  This level of detail is not necessary in the proposed duplicate, and is even going a bit *too granular* for the proposed duplicate's scope.

If we were to answer the proposed duplicate to include the details I need, it would also have to include the same details for every other character to cover the question's general scope.  At that point, you're nearly covering the entire content of the [Mass Effect 3 section](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance#Mass_Effect_3) in the Romance article on Mass Effect Wiki.  Questions that are *actually* reaching for that much information though, are generally closed as Not A Real Question.

**EDIT 2**

Question has been edited for clarification.  Most of the original content is the same, but the title has been changed and a line has been added to specify I'm not looking for a multi-romance play-through.  Please re-evaluate the question for re-opening.

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question, but the correct way of handling this would be to offer a bounty on the original question asking for specifics relating to Diana Allers, rather than opening a second question.

Comment: You wouldn't even necessarily have to offer a bounty. You could just leave a comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your recent edit to the question I believe your question is now fine, and five other users seem to agree with me since it has since been re-opened.

<s>I wasn't one of the closers, but your questions is a duplicate. A complete answer to the question [Can you romance multiple people?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54915/can-you-romance-multiple-people) should cover any special cases, including your Diana Allers example. Situations like this are why comments and bounties exist. Leave a comment on the accepted answer asking for a specific answer, and if that doesn't work you should consider adding a bounty.</s>

Comment: What if the question was about something more obscure than Mass Effect?  There's a very good chance that you'd get no response at all, leaving a comment asking for more.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Like I stated in my answer, if a comment doesn't work a bounty would be the next logical step.

Comment: I'm not certain that Diana Allers *is* a special case.  (Special case, for the purposes of the proposed duplicate question, being where you could *actually* fully romance multiple people.)  She may only be unique in that her lock-in point doesn't come until her final romance scene - something which would be out-of-scope for the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Agreed with OP, "When do you confirm a monogamous relationship with X?" is not covered by "Can you pursue another relationship after entering a monogamous one?"  The titles just weren't that clear.

Comment: I know that this will probably get drowned out in flames, but may I state for the record that I'm frankly sick and tired of "well this is why bounties exist!!!" being thrown around as a defense/short-circuit for bad answers? Especially when a cited duplicate is ridiculously old?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh: If you feel that strongly about it, you should make a meta topic. We're well aware that the bounty system isn't perfect, and if you'd like to outline the issues and open up discussion for an alternative please do.

Comment: @Wipqozn I'm not going to bother because I know the outcome. I'm well aware that I'm dramatically in the minority for believing that "duplicates" that are either asking for an updated answer or a narrow sub-sect of a larger query aren't duplicates (or problematic) at all and find no merit in belaboring the point.

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I'm not exactly clear I get what you mean by "defense/short-circuit for bad answers" - especially the answers part. You can't bounty answers. (I understand you don't want to rehash it, although it's hardly fair to blame others for a non constructive policy discussion if you give policy discussion such a non constructive start.)

Comment: @badp "This answer doesn't answer my question and the question is too broad to really hit the crux of what I want, but if I ask what I want, it gets closed as a duplicate and told to 'just add a comment/bounty'." is basically what I mean. I don't foresee any change to that.